# Weird issue with composer.phar

Tags: composer-php

I have composer.phar which was working great on my ubuntu server, then today when I try to use it I get nothing. When I run "php composer.phar" for example, I see no output at all (even with -v)

I tried to download new composer.phar which did not solve the issue.

My PHP:

> PHP 5.5.5-1+debphp.org~precise+2 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2013 12:57:03)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright
>   (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Any chance you've had a rootkit installed or the php binary's been replaced with a malicious one?

Comment: huhm, I wonder if that can be the case, is there any way to check that? Chkrootkit seems to report no issue.

Comment: I'd start by checking the php binary; `ls -al \`which php\`` should find it for you. As far as detecting rootkits... well, that's sort of the point of them.. to hide.

Comment: I get 
'lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Nov  6 17:01 /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php'. Also, I removed and reinstalled php, same issue. PHP is running fine with other apps though.

Comment: So it turned out that my zoneinfo got corrupted which caused PHP to mal-function. Fixed it by restoring zoneinfo. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Wow, I would never have guessed that zoneinfo was to blame! How in the world were you able to arrive at that?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling: I posted the issue on Github, Seldaek pointed me to the right direction when he said I could use strace to track down what went wrong. The strace revealed the error with timezone so since I was working with zoneinfo on this server before I suspected I did something stupid which caused the issue.

Comment: Nice detective work. If you post an answer, I'll definitely +1 it.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the issue on Github, Seldaek pointed me to the right direction when he said I could use strace to track down what went wrong. The strace revealed the error with timezone so since I was working with zoneinfo on this server before I suspected I did something stupid which caused the issue.

I think the main point here is that sometimes the error is not what it seems to be, and with the right suggestion and right tool you can dig deeper to find out the root cause.